# How to apply Cluster Source for Circle geom in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

I'm trying to apply [clustering](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Cluster-Cluster.html) to circle features. Having read the documentation it seems that for anything different then a point a *geometryFunction* needs to be defined: my attempt looks like this:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    geometryFunction: function(feature){
        let circlePoint = new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter());
        return circlePoint;
    },
    distance: 0,
    source: source,
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var styles = [style1];
        if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Circle') {
            style2.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
            style2.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius() / (180 * resolution));
            styles.push(style2);
        }
        return styles;
    },
    updateWhileAnimating: true,
    visible: true

});
```

and an example feature I add:

```
circle = new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.transform([_lon, _lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 1);
feature=new ol.Feature({
geometry: circle
});
```

I tried this with 5000 circles with different distance argument for the cluster, and it shows them at first load then they disappear when I change zoom level. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: styles used:

```
var style1 = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 255,0, 0.3)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#737373',
            width: 2
        })
    });
var style2 = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/photoshop-tree-top-view-png-3.png'
        })
    });
```

Comment: The clusters will be point geometries.  What are you using in `style1` to style points?

Comment: @Mike I added it to the text... Is it possible to make them circles back again? (maybe with size proportional to how many of them were clustered together)

Comment: Seems like this example might do something like what you want (just use your "tree" icon for the individual markers): https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a style function such as this, you would need to multiple the size of the cluster by a value appropriate to you application to get a radius

```
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var geometry;
        var features = feature.get('features');
        if (features) {
             // this is cluster
             if (features.length == 1) {
                 // cluster of 1, use that feature
                 geometry = features[0].getGeometry();
             } else {
                 // more than 1, use a circle based on size of the cluster
                 geometry = new ol.geom.Circle(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), features.length * ???);
             }
        } else {
             // some other feature, not a cluster
             geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        }
        style1.setGeometry(geometry):
        var styles = [style1];
        if (geometry.getType() == 'Circle') {
            style2.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(geometry.getCenter()));
            style2.getImage().setScale(geometry.getRadius() / (180 * resolution));
            styles.push(style2);
        }
        return styles;
    },
```

Comment: I'll try more with this one, so far the window blocks completely, I'm thinking because it uses style instantiation everytime and in their cluster example I noticed them using a cache for it... but I think this is the right direction...